# Skinning iOS application

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, interface-builder, skinning

Is there any solution for skinning the iOS application.
The more detailed requirement is:
1. The app can change its look in runtime.
2. New skins can be downloaded into Documents dir and read from there.
3. If the skin is damaged, the application has to use a default skin and not crash.

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to target iOS 5, taking a look at the [UIAppearance](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIAppearance) protocol.

Comment: It does solve 2 and 3. Define your style in XML (or other format) and read the file and adjust your UI.